# Replace whole string if it contains substring in pandas dataframe based on dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to replace data in column 'Place' with data from the dictionary i created. The column 'Place' contains a substring (not case sensitive) of the dictionary key. I cannot get either of my methods to work any guidance is appreciated.

```
incoming_df = pd.DataFrame({'First_Name' : ['John', 'Chris', 'renzo', 'Laura', 'Stan', 'Russ', 'Lip', 'Hick', 'Donald'],
                            'Last_Name' : ['stanford', 'lee', 'Olivares', 'Johnson', 'Stanley', 'Russaford', 'Lipper', 'Hero', 'Lipsey'],
                            'location' : ['Grant Elementary', 'Code Academy', 'Queen Prep', 'Waves College', 'duke Prep', 'california Academy', 'SF College Prep', 'San Ramon Prep', 'San Jose High']})

df = pd.DataFrame({'FirstN': [],
                        'LastN':[],
                        'Place': []})

# re index based on data given
df = df.reindex(incoming_df.index)

# copy data over to new dataframe
df['LastN'] = incoming_df.loc[:, incoming_df.columns.str.contains('Last', case=False)]
df['FirstN'] = incoming_df.loc[:, incoming_df.columns.str.contains('First', case=False)]
df['Place'] = incoming_df.loc[:, incoming_df.columns.str.contains('School|Work|Site|Location', case=False)]

places = { 'Grant' : 'DEF Grant Elementary',
                    'Code' : 'DEF Code Academy',
                    'Queen' : 'DEF Queen Preparatory High School',
                    'Waves' : 'DEF Waves College Prep',
                    'Duke' : 'DEF Duke Preparatory Institute',
                    'California' : 'DEF California Academy',
                    'SF College' : 'DEF San Francisco College',
                    'San Ramon' : 'DEF San Ramon Prep',
                    'San Jose' : 'DEF San Jose High School' }

# replace dictionary values with values in Place (results in NAN values inside 'Place' column
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(places.keys()))
extracted = df.Place.str.extract(pat, expand=False).dropna()
df['Place'] = extracted.apply(lambda x: places[x])

# Also tried this method but did not work
df['Place'] = df['Place'].replace(places)

# original df
    FirstN   LastN      Place
0   John    stanford    Grant Elementary
1   Chris   lee         Code Academy
2   renzo   Olivares    Queen Prep
3   Laura   Johnson     Waves College
4   Stan    Stanley     duke Prep
5   Russ    Russaford   california Academy
6   Lip     Lipper      SF College Prep
7   Hick    Hero        San Ramon Prep
8   Donald  Lipsey      San Jose High

# target df
    FirstN   LastN      Place
0   John    Stanford    DEF Grant Elementary
1   Chris   Lee         DEF Code Academy
2   Renzo   Olivares    DEF Queen Preparatory High School
3   Laura   Johnson     DEF Waves College Prep
4   Stan    Stanley     DEF Duke Preparatory Institute
5   Russ    Russaford   DEF California Academy
6   Lip     Lipper      DEF San Francisco College
7   Hick    Hero        DEF San Ramon Prep
8   Donald  Lipsey      DEF San Jose High School
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this loop solved my issue

```
for k, v in dic.items():
    df['Place'] = np.where(df['Place'].str.contains(k, case=False), v, df['Place'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension, and making use of `next` to short circuit and avoid wasted iteration.

```
df.assign(Place=[next((v for i in df.Place if i in k.lower()), None) for k,v in dic.items()])

               Place    User
0    Heights College  arenzo
1  Queens University  brenzo
2       York Academy  crenzo
3    Danes Institute  drenzo
4    Duke University  erenzo
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but get error STOP Iteration. I updated my code sample above to reflect my actual code better sorry about that.

Comment: You will get that error if a value is *not* a substring of any of your dictionary keys

Comment: Not sure why i am getting the error then. I think all the values are substrings of the dictionary keys

Comment: @RenzoOlivares try passing a default argument to `next`, so try: `df.assign(Place=[next((v for i in df.Place if i in k.lower()), None) for k,v in dic.items()])`

Comment: I tried that but get a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` and `loc`

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    df.loc[df['Place'].apply(lambda x: x in key.lower()), 'Place'] = value
```

Comment: did not work updated sample code above to better reflect my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

This is challenging given the string mismatch on 'Place'. Some naive workarounds:

1) You can utilize an index mapping, reformatting your dict to:

```
dic = {'1' : 'Heights College',
  '2' : 'Queens University',
  '3' : 'York Academy',
  '4' : 'Danes Institute',
  '5' : 'Duke University'}
```

Then use a map from your dict to df index:

```
df['Place'] = df.index.to_series().map(dic)
```

2) Alternatively, if your user column is unique you could replicate the above, edit your dic to map to user and then apply a similar df.map.If your user column is unique, you could try using map which performs a lookup based on user to your dict and return place.

```
dic = {'arenzo' : 'Heights College',
  'brenzo' : 'Queens University',
  'crenzo' : 'York Academy',
  'drenzo' : 'Danes Institute',
  'erenzo' : 'Duke University'}


df['Place'] = df['User'].map(dic)
```

Comment: My users are unique but multiple users can be assigned to the same place.I updated my sample code to better reflect my actual code. Thanks for your help!